# Why this image is so large despite small dimension

Tags: security, compression, image-size

I have any image which is 760x400 in dimension but it about 7MB in size. it comes out clean on VirustTotal.com and even Image Meta doesnt show anything unusual other than lots of text info.

Since i cant upload that image her due to size limitation am sharing link for image https://ibb.co/MRxtjrx

Screenshot of Image Meta for reference as this online Image meta doesn't give sharable information.

Can anyone tell me why this image is so large despite small in dimension and what information in Image Meta is irrelevant

This question may sound off teh topic but this image is being used on website so out of curiosity i am trying to find why this image is so large

[image]

Comment: You could ask "How do I optimize an image for my website", but "what is wrong with this image" is not going to help anybody with a similar problem in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The file is suffering from something called Metadata Bloat. Basically, there's a TON of data in the "history section" of the file itself. This usually happens either because (1) the Photoshop they used to save it was malfunctioning somehow, or (2) they were playing around with the code of the file itself and dumped a bunch of trash in it.

Here are some quick references about the issue: https://community.adobe.com/t5/photoshop/inflated-jpg-file-size-photoshop-document-ancestors-metadata/td-p/8055434?page=1

https://prepression.blogspot.com/2017/06/metadata-bloat-photoshopdocumentancestors.html